# Get selected radio button value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically created radio buttons and have assigned them ids. Now when i try,

```
function updateAO(id2) {
    var status = $('input[name=id2]:checked').val();
    alert(status);
}
```

It prints undefined. Can anyone please tell how to get this value.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: add your html as well.

Comment: If the input isnt checked at the time, no value will be returned. Try removing `:checked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector will only select inputs currently checked, if the passed input isnt checked at the time, status will remain unset, try changing your JS to:

```
function updateAO(id2) {
    var status = $('input[name='+id2+']').val();
    alert(status);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using your parameter correctly.

```
var status = $('input[name="' + id2 + '"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected radio button value use

```
function updateAO(id2) {
    var status = $('input[name=id2]:checked').val();
    alert(status);
}
```

To select normal radio button use

```
function updateAO(id2) {
    var status = $('input[name=id2]').val();
    alert(status);
}
```